# Define elements of a package spec in multiple scripts?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Say I have a package with a spec defined in **mySpec.pks**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PKG AS 
    PROCEDURE TEST_1 ( asdf int );
    PROCEDURE TEST_2 ( asdf int, asdf2 char );
END;
```

Is it possible to split the implementation of each procedure into multiple body "CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY" statements?
I'm imagining something like this for the body files:

**test1.pkb** ( only has implementation of procedure *TEST_1* )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG AS 
    PROCEDURE TEST_1 ( asdf int ) IS
    BEGIN
        --do stuff
    END;
END;
```

**test2.pkb** (only has implementation of procedure *TEST_2*)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG AS 
    PROCEDURE TEST_2 ( asdf int, asdf2 char ) IS
    BEGIN
        --do stuff
    END;
END;
```

Comment: I do not think so.  Why would you want to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not.  A package body is a single entity, there must be a single `CREATE` statement.  Just like the entire implementation of an object has to be in a single file, the entire implementation of a package must be in a single file.

The desire to split the implementation across multiple files would tend to imply to me that the package itself is trying to do too much and that the entire package needs to be refactored into two or more smaller, more self-contained packages.

Answer (score 5):

You can't quite do what you suggest, but it is possible to split the package body *file* into smaller sections, as long as you're using SQL*Plus to load the package. I'm not suggesting this is a good idea, and I'd generally agree with Justin about refactoring your design if you're doing this for size reasons. But just because you can:

Define the package body in a script, say `test_pkg.pkb`, and 'include' sub-files for each procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG AS 
@test_1.sql
@test_2.sql
END TEST_PKG;
/
```

Then in `test_1.sql`:

```
PROCEDURE TEST_1 ( asdf int ) IS
BEGIN
    --do stuff
END TEST_1;
```

And in `test_2.sql`:

```
PROCEDURE TEST_2 ( asdf int, asdf2 char ) IS
BEGIN
    --do stuff
END TEST_2;
```

When you execute the script it's still seen as a single `create` statement by the parser.

You can't run the 'included' files separately, they'll only work as part of the package body load - `sqlplus @test_pkg.pkb` - so if your aim is to allow just one procedure to be reloaded independently this won't work.

There is also another downside, in that any compilation error messages will refer to line numbers in the package body overall, so you'd have to work out which of the sub-files the relevant code is in, which is doable but a bit tricky. And in the same vein, what's stored in `user_source` won't match what is in your files. It's kind of like looking at a pre-processed C or Pro*C file I suppose, related but not always easy to reconcile with the original.

So... probably not worth the effort and potential for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Each package spec corresponds to one and only one package body.

You can create 2 package specs and 2 package bodies to separate the functions if you like.

The spec has a purpose and does a lot of things, like making certain procedures/functions callable by other packages/proc/funcs, declaring package global variables, specifying things like "authid current_user" and etc...

Oracle has pl/sql well thought through :)